# .NET 4.6.2 shared domain assembly loading

Tags: .net, clr, .net-assembly

We have multiple web applications running on one app pool in IIS. So they have different appdomains within one process. We decided to save some memory by signing and moving most of libraries into GAC so they can load to shared domain only once. According to [this](https://www.shanebart.com/aspnet-assembly-interning/) tool we have everything in place and there's nothing more to intern. Some of our libraries are marked as DomainNeutral and loaded to shared domain. But the problem is that most of them are not shared and are duplicated in every appdomain.

So the question is: what can prevent libs from sharing and is there a possibility to debug CLR assembly loading process to see the reasons of not flagging them as DomainNeutral?

P.S. A majority of such common libs like System.Web.Http aren't shared too while System.Web is.